# Android Studio: Facebook Profile wont load

Tags: android, facebook, profile, pic

I recently just noticed that my profile picture is not loading and in my database it says "https://platform-lookaside.fbsbx.com/platform/profilepic/?asid=3143323662344523&height=200&width=200&ext=1566545362&hash=AeS-asAF_-qCWALi" 
can anyone please help me out? it'll be a huge help. thanks

below is my code

public void getUserDetailsFromFb(AccessToken accessToken) {

```
    GraphRequest req = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(accessToken, new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(final JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
            try {
                Log.d("response101", String.valueOf(response));
                if (object.has("email")) {
                    mEmail = object.getString("email");
                } else {
                    mEmail = "";
                }
                mPhotoUrl = object.getJSONObject("picture").getJSONObject("data").getString("url");
                mId = object.getString("id");
                mName = object.getString("name");

                mUser = new User();
                mUser.setiD(mId.toString());
                mUser.setFirstName(mName.replace(mName.substring(mName.lastIndexOf(" ")), ""));
                mUser.setLastName(mName.substring(mName.lastIndexOf(" ")).replace(" ", ""));
                mUser.setEmail(mEmail);
                mUser.setPhotoUrl(mPhotoUrl);

                AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(accessToken.getToken());
                mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                        .addOnCompleteListener(LoginActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                                    Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");
                                    //check if user already exists; if yes, proceed to userMainActivity
                                    databaseUser.child(mUser.getiD()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                            if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
                                                //we don't need the whole user object just the userId
                                                Log.d(TAG,"iddd: " + mUser.getiD());
                                                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, UserMainActivity.class).putExtra("userId", mUser.getiD()));
                                            } else {
                                                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, EditProfileActivity.class).putExtra("user", mUser));
                                            }
                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                                        }
                                    });
                                } else {
                                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                                    Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }
                        });
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "graph request error : " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,gender,birthday,picture.type(large)");
    req.setParameters(parameters);
    req.executeAsync();
}
```

Comment: Hello dev.hnh, in order to offer guidance with the issue that you're facing, I'd recommend including further information (for example: the code you're using to request the profile picture image from your database, etc.). Including any pertinent background information will give the community the best chance of assisting you. If you need any help adding information to your question, [these guidelines do a great job of illustrating what to include in a well-formed question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I apologize! I just added my code. Can you please see and check what seems to be causing the problem? It'll mean so much to me. Thanks